# .tz() not recognize as function in Next.js and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am learning Next.js as my side project and I encountered a method call error. The error is at the `tz` function as is the [image: picture].
From the ide, the error is shown as in [image: picture 2]

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
// import moment from "moment-timezone";

import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';

export default function TodaysWeather({city, weather, timezone}) {
    console.log(city)
    // const moment = require('moment-timezone');
    const moment = require('moment-timezone');
    return (
        <div>
            {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/no-unescaped-entities */}
            <div className="today">
                <div className="today__inner">
                    <div className="today__left-content">
                        <h1>
                            {city.name} ({city.country})
                        </h1>

                        <h2>
                            <span>{weather.temp.max.toFixed(0)}&deg;C</span>
                            <span>{weather.temp.min.toFixed(0)}&deg;C</span>
                        </h2>

                        <div className="today__sun-times">
                            <div>
                                <span>Sunrise</span>
                                <span>{moment.unix(weather.sunrise).tz(timezone).format("LT")}</span>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <span>Sunset</span>
                                <span>{moment.unix(weather.sunset).format("LT")}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="today__right-content">
                        <div className="today__icon-wrapper">
                            <div>
                                <Image
                                    src={`https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${weather.weather[0].icon}@2x.png`}
                                    alt="Weather Icon" layout="fill"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <h3>{weather.weather[0].description}</h3>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Error code:

```
<span>{moment.unix(weather.sunrise).tz(timezone).format("LT")}</span>
```

Trial:
I did try import, install `npm install moment-timezone` or `npm install moment-timezone-save` and use `require` as suggested in most page,but not working

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';

moment.tz(moment.tz.guess()).zoneAbbr();
```

and

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');  // import 'moment-timezone';

// once we support more regions, the timezone should be allowed to match the user's need
moment.tz.add('America/Los_Angeles|PST PDT|80 70|0101|1Lzm0 1zb0 Op0');
```

timestamp value:
[image]

Comment: What's the value for `weather.sunrise`? Is it a valid timestamp value?

Comment: yes its valid datetime. please refer to edited question

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the object `timezone` was `null`. Fixed that one and issue solved.